# How do I explicitely thread tasks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Suppose I have two functions:

```
Fun1();
Fun2();
```

These functions are independent and the task would be improved if I could run them in parallel (that is, run `Fun1` on one thread and `Fun2` on another. I am using Visual Studio 2012 - so **Open MP 2.0**.

Is there a *straight-forward* way (without any parallel region thread number testing or *for* loop dodginess) to achieve this? Does OpenMP provide this kind of functionality?

I tried looking at the `parallel` and `task` directives as a place to start but I find most of the literature thoroughly [incomprehensible](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.linux.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_task.html) and couldn't find any examples...

Comment: An important detail to know would be if you really only have 2 such functions that you invoke just once (or maybe a few times total). If it's that simple, using `std::thread` as in John Zwinck's answer is by far the easiest and most efficient solution. If you have a dozen functions that you call a thousand times, the solution by Massimiliano would be much preferrable (or, alternatively, implementing your own task queue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a `sections` work-sharing construct:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
#pragma omp section
  Fun1();
#pragma omp section
  Fun2();
}
```

Quoting from [OpenMP 2.0 specifications](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/cspec20.pdf) (sec. 2.4.2):

> The sections directive identifies a noniterative work-sharing
>   construct that specifies a set of constructs that are to be divided
>   among threads in a team. Each section is executed once by a thread in
>   the team.

Answer (score 5):

C++11:

```
std::thread thread1(Fun1);
Fun2(); // runs on main thread
thread1.join(); // wait for completion
```

If you don't have C++11, you can replace `std::thread` with `boost::thread` and do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, why not using native threads or some wrappers around them? Open MP, as far as i know is much more powerful, than a simple thread runner tool. Of course, you can mark some flag variable as shared or private and check it inside parallelling pragma or perhaps obtain appropriate results with using schedule directive (don't remember exactly all OMP features), but...

- You've got only couple of tasks
- It's not really the parallel computing, it's not eveb some kind of primitive thread pool, just the same problem as that of getting GUI and calculations in 2 single threads
- You haven't told anything about synchronization or complex thread cooperation

Looks like u don't really need Open MP.

Comment: I wonder what or whom you target your `Yeah` at? It somewhat confuses me :S

Comment: Sorry, i may be not too good in english, but i definitely agree with the simple, yet best solution John Zwinck proposed.
Author asked about Open MP, seems he insisted on it, but without proper reason.
UPD: ops, there is another answer there. The page didn't get updated in time.

Comment: Ah I see :) Your english is good. However, regarding "Yeah", be aware that Stack Overflow is not a forum or thread system; all answers may be arbitrarily ordered ;)